# Message from application: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache2, passenger

What do I do about this?

```
App 1090 stdout: 
App 1090 stderr: Ignoring executable-hooks-1.4.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.4.2
App 1090 stderr: Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.3.2
App 1090 stderr: Ignoring taglib-ruby-0.7.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine taglib-ruby --version 0.7.1
App 1090 stdout:
```

Trace on [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/iWbXGuu9).

Comment: you'll have to post your apache configs, i think your passengerruby and your ruby with bundler probably aren't the same.

Comment: witch apache2 configs should i post? there are more then one. there is the main apach2.conf and there are the ones in the sub directories.

Comment: i'd start with posting `which ruby` rom your path, and whatever apache config defines     `PassengerRuby`